# Passport-Twitter - Error: Failed to find request token in session

Tags: node.js, twitter, passport.js

I am using passport-twitter to set up a twitter connect on my site. Users can connect by clicking on 'login' or on 'add new item'. The only difference between the 2 is that if they click on add new item, a modal window is supposed to open once theyre logged in.

To know on button they click, I store the url in `req.session.referrer`:

```
// route for twitter authentication and login
app.get('/auth/twitter', function(req, res, next){
    req.session.referrer = req.url;
    console.log(req.session);
    passport.authenticate('twitter')(req, res, next);
});

app.get('/auth/twitter/new', function(req, res, next){
    req.session.referrer = req.url;
    console.log(req.session);
    passport.authenticate('twitter')(req, res, next);
});

// handle the callback after twitter has authenticated the user
app.get('/auth/twitter/callback', function(req, res, next){
    var options = {
            successRedirect : '/twitter-user/signin',
            failureRedirect : '/'
        };

    console.log(req.session);
    if (req.session.referrer && req.session.referrer.indexOf('new') > -1) options.successRedirect = '/twitter-user/new';

    passport.authenticate('twitter', options)(req, res, next)
});
```

Everything works fine in my development environment but once online I get this error message:
Express

```
500 Error: Failed to find request token in session
at Strategy.OAuthStrategy.authenticate (/app/node_modules/passport-twitter/node_modules/passport-oauth1/lib/strategy.js:142:54)
...
```

My settings are set up properly in Twitter. Here is what I get with the logs:
For the request:

```
{ cookie: 
  { path: '/',
      _expires: null,
      originalMaxAge: null,
      httpOnly: true },
   passport: {},
   referrer: '/auth/twitter' }
```

For the callback:

```
{ cookie: 
    { path: '/',
      _expires: null,
      originalMaxAge: null,
      httpOnly: true },
   passport: {} }
```

Maybe it could be due to subdomain problem ( http://example.com vs http://www.example.com) as I don't have the pb locally.
How can I fix this?

Many thanks

EDIT: My API key is set up like this (as per this tutorial: http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/easy-node-authentication-twitter):

```
passport.use(new TwitterStrategy({

    consumerKey     : configAuth.twitterAuth.consumerKey,
    consumerSecret  : configAuth.twitterAuth.consumerSecret,
    callbackURL     : configAuth.twitterAuth.callbackURL

},function(token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {
    ...
    });
```

Comment: where do you have tour twitter api key setup?

Comment: I edited my question with the info. Please see above

Answer (score 4):

First if your callback is localhost and you are using express-session make sure the cookie secure option is set to false. e.g

```
// Express session
let sess = {
    secret: 'secret',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,

    cookie: {
        secure: false,
    }
}
```

You can also change that in production by

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    app.set('trust proxy', 1) // trust first proxy
    sess.cookie.secure = true // serve secure cookies
}
```

If that didn't work then check if you have set the cookie [sameSite](https://web.dev/samesite-cookies-explained/) option to Strict. Change it to Lax. e.g

```
let sess = {
    secret: 'secret',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,

    cookie: {
        secure: false,
        sameSite: 'Lax'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I got the same Error but solved it.. and here's what my issue was and the solution.

Actuality, it didn't like my redirect url "http:// localhost /auth/twitter/callback". I changed it to "http:// 127.0.0.1 /auth/twitter/callback". In my actual code, I had to keep it as localhost or I'd get errors about a missing token